# Rails naming convention for join tables to specialized tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get that if you have a posts and a categories table that the join table will be posts_categories. However you might have more than one type of category.

If we decide to create specialized category tables for each object type we would create a posts_categories table which would be a table of categories specifically for post objects. What would the many-to-many join table be called between posts and posts_categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would create the join table (`categorizations`) with additional column(s):

`rails g model Categorization post:references category:references new_column:new_type ....`

```
### models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end

## models/categorization
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category

  ## You can add new columns as many as you want, just like other tables
end

# models/category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can fully understand your question. But, if you want create a many-to-many relationship between Post and Category, you can try as bellow:

```
# post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :post_categories
   has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
end
```

and

```
#post_category.rb
class PostCategory < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :category
end
```

and

```
# category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :post_categories
   has_many :posts, through: :post_categories
end
```

Hope it helps.